# ios logic for a retina screen

Tags: ios, uiimage, retina-display

For just about everything I use `image.png` and `image@2x.png` which the device always uses the right image at the right place.

However, I'm manually adding SOME images like so:

```
theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

How do I decide if I need an @2x image or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You don't...**

iOS will automatically look for @2x images, when using `imageNamed:`.

Note: if you need to know if the current device has a retina display, for another purpose, you may use `[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] scale ]`:

[UIScreen Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)

Comment: You are correct. However, for some reason the frame of the image is still the 1x size. I suspect it's because of the 2x dpi effects when on a retina device. Anyway, your reference to the scale is what I needed. +1 for being pro.

Comment: The frame will be in "1x size" because you have to remember that the coordinate system is now in points, not pixels. In the case of a retina display, 2px = 1pt, so a frame of 0,0,320,480 spans the entire device (on an iPhone/Touch) regardless of if it's retina or not.